# Calculating the $k$th derivative of $F(x) = x \sin (x^n)$ where the $F^k(0)$ does not equal $0$.

Tags: derivatives

I have a function $F(x) = x \sin (x^N)$  where $N$ is a natural number. I need to compute $F^k(0)$ for the smallest positive integer $k$ such that $F^k(0)\neq 0$. 
$F^k$ is the $k$th derivative of the function $F$.

I am confused on where to go with this question. I first started with the MacLaurin series expansion. Then I tried individually differentiating the function.

Could someone please help me with the question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems that the first such function is where $k=n+1$.

Comment: Since you already mentioned MacLaurin, use $\sin(x) = x + o(x^3)$ to argue $F(x) = x \sin(x^N) = x^{N+1} + o(x^{N+2})$. Now, what is $F(x) / x^{N+1}$ for $x\to 0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you differentiate, each resulting term will have some polynomial multiplied on it (expect for the sine after the first differentiation, but $\sin(0)=0$, so we can't stop there), until a term appears where all the powers of $x$ have been differentiated away. This happens after $N+1$ differentiations. Each time a factor will come out of differentiation a polynomial (i.e. $\left(x^n\right)'=nx^{n-1},$ $\left(nx^{n-1}\right)'=n(n-1)x^{n-2},$ etc.), so the first $k$ that satisfies your demand will make $F^k(0)$ evaluate to $$F^k(0)=(N+1)!$$

*Sorry about the clumsy explanation; I hope the idea is clear though*.

Answer (score 0):

I think comparing Maclaurin series is a nice way to to this.  We have a power series representation
\begin{align*}
    F(x) &= x \sin(x^N) =  x \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k(x^N)^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}
    = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k x^{N(2k+1)+1}}{(2k+1)!}
\end{align*}
On the other hand, since $F$ is analytic, we know
$$
    F(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(0)x^n}{n!}
$$
Now compare the coefficients of each side of the equation:
$$
    \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(0)x^n}{n!}=
    \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k x^{N(2k+1)+1}}{(2k+1)!}
$$
Since the right-hand side starts with the power $N+1$ (when $k=0$), the coefficients $\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$ are zero for $0 \leq n \leq N$.  Equating the coefficients of $x^{N+1}$, we have
$$
    \frac{f^{(N+1)}(0)}{(N+1)!} = \frac{(-1)^0}{1!} = 1
$$
so $f^{(N+1)}(0)=(N+1)!$.